# Mulit-module application maven

Tags: java, maven, maven-release-plugin, multi-module

I've got multi module maven project, where main project depend on sub-module. Every dependency of sub-module is define by version like this: `${pom.version}`. I use maven release plug-in. If I try to prepare release, I've got an error about missing version of sub-module.

Example:

main pom is on version `1.0`, I try to release it. Maven build every sub-module to version `1.1`, then try to build parent, and then crash. Because it can't find `sub-module-1.1`.

I don't know how to tell maven to build, and immediate install to local-repo every sub-module witch it build. I use maven2.

My pom:

```xml
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.voncuver</groupId>
<artifactId>voncuver</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>multimodule</name>

<modules>
    <module>mod1</module>
    <module>mod2</module>
</modules>

(...)

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>mod1</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.voncuver</groupId>
            <version>${pom.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <artifactId>mod2</artifactId>
            <groupId>com.voncuver</groupId>
            <version>${pom.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
(...)
```

Comment: do you explicitly set the version of each sub module to ${pom.version}? The version property is inherited from the parent...

Comment: First could you post your pom's (excerpt is ok) furthermore don't use pom.version better is project.version

Comment: The release plugin will automatically update dependency versions from within the reactor, so there is actually no need to reference ${project.version} also keep in mind, what @khmarbaise said as ${pom.version} is deprecated in favour of ${project.version}

Answer (score 1):

You should probably post a bit more of your project structure, but typically a multimodule project looks like this:

```
project
   mod1
   mod2
   mod3
   pom.xml
```

The main pom.xml would have "pom" packaging type, and have a  section in it to build everything else:

```
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<modules>
  <module>mod1</module>
  <module>mod2</module>
  <module>mod3</module>
</modules>
```

Then, the surest way to make sure things build properly is to execute:

> mvn clean install

Without the "install", it's highly possible that things might not be found in the maven reactor, especially depending on what version of maven you are using (and a few other factors).

Comment: The OP has problems with the `maven-release-plugin` and it is much more complicated than just running `mvn install`. I am not sure that this answer is going to help much since the question is not that clear. At the moment I will downvote, sorry...

Comment: @maba My point being that release plugin or no, there's not enough information about his project structure for anyone to give any help.  I merely suggested what the structure should look like in case it was not relatively "standard".

Comment: Run `mvn release:perform` will execute the predefined Maven phase `mvn deploy`, which will execute the `mvn install` automatically.

Comment: If your project will not build from a clean local repository without going as far as the install phase, then you are doing Maven wrong.

A good maven project should build correctly if you do the following

    rm -rvf ~/.m2/repository &&
    mvn clean verify

If you need to go as far as install, you have structured your project incorrectly or are relying on crappy plugins

Comment: I can build mu project in local repository. Just type mvn clean install. I've got structure similar to witch Matt present. I've got problem when I try to release. I try release by mvn release:prepare. Plug-in ask question's resolve dependency: yes, when ask about version, I type to increment version "1.1->1.2". It build every sub-module, ex. it build and release version 1.1, and increment in POM(sub-module) to version 1.2. And if it try to build parent project version 1.1 it crash because it can't find dependency to sub-module's on version 1.1. This version witch it build a while ago.